# Button with BackgroundImage sizing automatically even when AutoSize is disabled

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, button

I have a button in which i have initialized a background image and disabled the AutoSizing options and initialized a default size to button. But the button is getting smaller size than the given size, even when Autosizing are disabled.

```
firstButton.Size = new Size(28,28);
firstButton.AutoSize = false;
firstButton.BackgroundImage = GetBitMap("First.png");
firstButton.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Center;
```

But the size of button automatically changed to 23, when comes to view.

Could anyone please let me know, how to avoid autosizing of the button with image ?

Regards,
Amal Raj U.

Comment: If you set the size (28x28) and take a screenshot the size is a little bit less like (26x26). It is normal. You might experience something like that. Try and set a large size like `firstButton.Size = new Size(100, 100);` and see if the button get small.

Answer (score 0):

Since I am not allowed to add any comments because of my low reputation, I will ask you here if the button is anchored in the control where it is placed. (if this is the solution I will edit my answer later) Check the Anchor property of the button.

Comment: I have tried with Anchor.None and also valid anchors. But button size is decreasing automatically.

Comment: Is it just that button that behaves like that? Or all the controls in the form?